# Entorno para aprendizaje por refuerzo

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, inteligencia-artificial

Tienen algún ejemplo de entorno desarrollado en matlab para aprendizaje por refuerzo. Es decir:
Algún ejemplo claro como se desarrolla un entorno para esto?

Saludos

Andres

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en recomendaciones sobre recursos terminan cerradas

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822